# database connection in GeoServer

Tags: redis, database-connection, geoserver

I am going to use redis as the web cache for geoserver, so I need to understand the database connection in geoserver. I have imported geoserver in Eclipse, and there are two projects named gs-sec-jdbc and gs-web-sec-jdbc. I do not know what the “sec" means and what are the differences between these two projects. Any help or tutorial is appreciated！ Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two modules are part of the security subsystem (gs-web-sec-jdbc is the web based user interface). They are almost certainly **not** the modules you are looking for.

If you intend to use redis to store WMS output images then you need to look at how [GeoWebCache](http://geowebcache.org/) works.

If you want to provide a cache between GeoServer and a JDBC database then you will need to explore [GeoTools'](http://geotools.org) [JDBC datastore](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/jdbc/index.html) mechanism.

Comment: Thanks, iant. I think GeoTools' JDBC datastore mechanism is the one I am looking for.

Comment: By the way, is there any tutorial about geoserver source code?